# OpenGL blank screen?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning OpenGL from book, I did exactly what is in the book, but when I run it (Eclipse C++ IDE) I get just blank screen.
Book is "OpenGL guide for programmers". I think the error is in Reshape(), but code is from book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

typedef const char* String;

String TITLE = "OpenGL";
int HEIGHT = 480;
int WIDTH = HEIGHT / 9 * 12;

void Update(int time){
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 10, Update, 1);
}

void Init(){
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void Render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(1.0, 2.0, 1.0); // Modeling transformation
    glutWireCube(1.0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Reshape(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow(TITLE);

    glewExperimental = true;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(err!=GLEW_OK){
        exit(1);
    }

    Init();
    Update(1);
    glutDisplayFunc(Render);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find this book. Maybe you should choose another one, which will teach you modern OpenGL.

Comment: This is a book http://www.ics.uci.edu/~gopi/CS211B/opengl_programming_guide_8th_edition.pdf

Comment: That's very interesting because this book is about modern OpenGL. And it's called OpenGL Programming Guide a.k.a "Red Book". Can you tell me on exactly what page is that example?

Comment: You'll need a projection matrix. Whenever you set up a view matrix, like you do with `gluLookAt()`, you'll mostly need a matching projection matrix. Otherwise the geometry you render will all be outside the visible range. Pretty much any tutorial should show you how to set up these transformations correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes reshape function is definitely wrong

use that

```
void Reshape(GLsizei w,GLsizei h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    GLfloat aspectRatio;
    aspectRatio = static_cast<GLfloat>(w) / static_cast<GLfloat>(h);

    gluPerspective(45.0,aspectRatio,1.0,4000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

instead